# Cicle for and function behaviour in Jupyter

Tags: python, function, for-loop

probably my question is very styupoid, but my problem is that if i writer cycle for within a function, the result isn't saved, but if i do the cycle for not in the fction, the behaviour is correct. Where i'm failing writing my function? Thank you for the time spent for me

```
def infoClean(liste, database):
    for i in liste:
        database = database[~(database['Username'].str.contains(i, case = False, na = False))]

infoClean(toRemove, twitter)
twitter.info()
```

This not working, but if i write:

```
for i in toRemove:
        twitter = twitter[~(twitter['Username'].str.contains(i, case = False, na = False))]

twitter.info()
```

This works. In this case infact the first database called twitter is update with the cycle for. Where I'm failing? Thank you to all for the patience and support

Comment: you may have to use `return database`  and run `twitter = infoClean(toRemove, twitter)`

Answer (score 1):

This is a call by reference vs call by value problem.

The variables you give to the function are copied and changes are only done to the copy. To get the changed version you need to return it from the function.

```
def infoClean(liste, database):
    for i in liste:
        database = database[~(database['Username'].str.contains(i, case = False, na = False))]
    return database

twitter = infoClean(toRemove, twitter)
twitter.info()
```

Comment: It doesn't work and I don't know why

Comment: thank you @Eumel this works, instead. I had an issue with The IDE pycharm. Thank you a lot!